# Is it possible to show image without toolbar with opencv's imshow?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, video, graphics

When OpenCV's imshow is invoked, it always shows a toolbar at the top of the image. Is there anyway to turn it off?

```
Mat frame;
bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);
imshow("MyVideo", frame);
if ( cvWaitKey(30) == 27 ) {
       break;
}
```

I'm using OpenCV 3.0 under ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

You can put `namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_GUI_NORMAL);` outside of the loop containing `imshow("MyVideo",frame);`.

For more details, see this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5afdf8410934fd099df85c75b2e0888b).

Comment: Hey, works! Strange stackoverflow has not covered this little topic. Thks.

Comment: @horaceT consider marking the answer, it helps the community.